# How to response XMLHttpRequest in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

By XMLHttpRequest, i send some data with

```
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 /** responseText is not available yet */) {
      const statusCode = xhr.status
      const responseText = xhr.responseText
      // some callback functions
    }
  }
  xhr.open('POST', url, true /** async */)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  xhr.withCredentials = true 
  xhr.timeout = timeoutMillis 
  xhr.ontimeout = function (event) {
    // some time out error log
  }
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payloads))
```

and server side node.js server code is

```
   var httpPort = 3001
var http = require('http')
   ,qs = require('querystring');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.url + " "  + req.method);
   if( req.url == '/mytoken' && req.method == 'POST'){
        console.log('start');
        var body = [];
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
        req.on('data', function(chunk){
                body.push(chunk);
                console.log('GOT DATA: ' + body);
        });
        res.end('OK');
   }else{
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('404 ERROR');
   }
}).listen(httpPort);
```

I wrote server code like this. but, server did not send any response.

It should be statusCode 200 with responseText 'OK'.

I missed some? or did wrong way?

EDIT 1: server code editted and it read data that sent to me

Comment: what was the result of the first line `console.log(req.url + req.method);`

Comment: `console.log()` only informs the console/terminal. Use [`res.write()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) to send information to an HTTP client. Also, be aware of timing – the events don't occur immediately, so you're likely ending the `res` before the `req` has actually provided any `'data'`. Also listen for the [`'end'` event](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_event_end).

Comment: @reza /mytoken POST

Comment: @JonathanLonowski i wrote like 
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'textplain'});
res.end('OK');
didn't it mean that xhr can get xhr.statusCode to 200 and xhr.responseText to 'OK'?

Comment: @pebC Yes. Once the XHR's `readyState === 4` (i.e. the request is "Done"), its `statusCode` and `responseText` should be `200` and `'OK'`. Is that not the result you're seeing? If not, what is the result? How are you verifying them?

Comment: Note that the client-side snippet contains a typo – `xhr.status` should be `xhr.statusCode`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski i'm sorry. it is statusCode. my client always say "Disconnected, because no message in 10000ms"

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it'll need to put extra permission info on response head:

```
res.writeHead(200,{
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" // Allow access from other domains
});
res.write('Hello From Server   O w O !');
res.end();
```